# Arrange value_counts by month

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in my dataframe

| year-month |
| --- |
| 2020-01 |
| 2020-01 |
| 2020-01 |
| 2020-02 |
| 2020-02 |
| ... |
| 2021-06 |

This column is stored as an "object" type in my dataframe. I didn't convert it to a "datetime" type from the onset because then my values would change to "2020-01-01" instead(?)

Anyway, I wanted to get do a value_counts(), by month, so that I can plot it out subsequently. How can I order the value_counts() by month while reflecting the month as "Jan", "Feb"..."Dec" at the same time?

I've tried this:

```
pd.DateTime(df['year-month']).dt.month.value_counts().sort_index()
```

However, the months are reflected as "1","2"..."12" which isn't what I want

I then tried this:

```
pd.DateTime(df['year-month']).dt.strftime('%b').value_counts().sort_index()
```

Which gives me the month by "Jan","Feb"..."Dec" indeed but now it's sorted by alphabetical order instead of by the actual month sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this point of yours:

```
result = pd.to_datetime(df["year-month"]).dt.strftime("%b").value_counts()
```

we can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the result so that the index becomes the month name abbreviations in order. This can be borrowed from the `calendar` module:

```
import calendar

# slicing out the first since it is empty string
month_names = calendar.month_abbr[1:]

# reindex and put 0 to those that didn't appear at all
result = result.reindex(month_names, fill_value=0)
```

to get

```
>>> result

Jan    3
Feb    2
Mar    0
Apr    0
May    0
Jun    1
Jul    0
Aug    0
Sep    0
Oct    0
Nov    0
Dec    0
```

(The reason `calendar.month_abbr` has an empty string in the begining is because Python is 0-indexed but we say 2nd month is February; so putting an empty string there results in `month_abbr[2] == "February"`.)

Comment: My reputation is too low to give you an upvote but thank you! I'll combine the syntax into a single line: pd.to_datetime(df["year-month"]).dt.strftime("%b").value_counts().reindex(calendar.month_abbr[1:])